# jqxgrid is overlapping with datepicker

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I'm using jqxgrid (http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm) and datepicker (jQuery).

When I click on the textbox to open calendar, it's appearing under the jqxgrid column. Please see the attach picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

issue is solve. set the zindex in  style

.jqx-grid-column-header{z-index:0!important;}

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to update the z-index of your datepicker, not to jqxGrid